# QueryDSL,Hibernate delete Child table row on delete of parent table row

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to delete the parent table row and watching if it cascades (the delete) on the child table rows.
Parent and Child Table Entity with java annotations are:

```
//Table details
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT_TABLE")
//Mandatory Column details
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="PARENT_TABLE_ID")
private Integer id;
.
.
.
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "parentTable")
private Set<ChildTable> setChildTable;
//Child table entity details:
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_TABLE")
//Column details
@Id
@Column(name = "PARENT_TABLE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
.
.
private ParentTable parentTable;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_TABLE_ID")
public ParentTable getPatentTable() {
   return parentTable;
}

 //QueryDSL to Delete child table row, looks like this:
HibernateDeleteClause query = new HibernateDeleteClause(getSession(),QChildTable.childTable);
Path<?> idPath = QChildTable.childTable;
 query.where(((NumberPath<?>)idPath).in((Number[]) ids)).execute();
 //QueryDSL to Delete parent table rows, looks like this:
HibernateDeleteClause query = new HibernateDeleteClause(getSession(),QParentTable.parentTable);
Path<?> idPath = QParentTable.parentTable;
 query.where(((NumberPath<?>)idPath).in((Number[]) ids)).execute();
```

If i delete the child and then try to delete the parent table rows, it works fine.
Looking for help to delete the Parent and Child table rows all at a time the way insert works. Like Creating ParentTable object assigning the data and insert , inserts both Parent table and Child table rows.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Added the attribute orphanRemoval = true for the One to many mapping as below:
`@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "parentTable",orphanRemoval = true)`

but does not help

Comment: Getting the below exception with and without cascade attribute for child table:
`@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` 
OR
`@ManyToOne`

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: update or delete on table "PARENT_TABLE" violates foreign key constraint "fk7dfcef12c1324147" on table "CHILD_TABLE"
  Detail: Key (PARENT_TABLE_ID)=(1065) is still referenced from table "CHILD_TABLE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately DELETE clauses in JPQL do not cascade to related entities, so you will need to use the API for cascading deletes or updates:

```
A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and its subclasses. 
It does not cascade to related entities.
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question to delete the child table rows when the parent table row is deleted.

Parent Table Object's mapping to getChildTableSet:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "parentTable", orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<ChildTable> getSetChildTable() {
    return setChildTable;
}
```

Child Table Object's mapping for ParentTable Column:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_TABLE_ID")
public ParentTable getParentTable() {
    return parentTable;
}
```

The rest of the getter and setter methods remain same, the ID's of both Parent-Child tables are auto generated, Just take of the mappings, the rest should work fine.